# Is ist a good idea to use AngularUI bootstrap integration?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-ui

I wanted to start a little test project with twitters bootstrap. To bring it all together I wanted to try out AngularJS, maybe together with requirejs as AMD solution. I saw there is a [AngularJS bootstrap integration](http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/) and I was asking myself if it's a good idea to use that instead of using the plain AngularJS and bootstrap aside.

Are there any benefits or should I use these two separately?
Can I use AngularUI together with bootstrap?

Comment: How can anyone answer this for you? Only you know what features you need.

Comment: Just to answer one part that is possible to answer: you can use both angular-ui and angular-ui/bootstrap. Otherwise I agree that it is impossible to evaluate for you. Check the deliverables and decide if they bring value for you, check project philosophy (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap#project-philosophy) to see if it fits etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Angular comes with directives and modules, so no other AMD solution necessary
- I find Bootstrap particularly good for the CSS and for that it works great with Angular (which does only JavaScript and HTML generation)
- If you find the [JavaScript part of Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html) useful and you're using Angular, then by all means go for [AngularJS Bootstrap integration](http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought someone might have already gathered some experience in that constellation. But I'll just go and try it out for myself.

Comment: AngularUI and AngularUI/Bootstrap is designed to be compatible with each other. There are no cross dependencies though so it's up to you if you wish to use both.